# Adding custom response header to IHttpActionResult class (or adding the Auth Token as a response)

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been trying to make a Login Control for my Web Api project. Everything works perfect, i have also handled the Token generation as well as the authentication functions. My main concern is, that i cannot deliver back as a response of the request, the Token which i have generated as an Auth method for the user. I have tried several things, yet none of them work.

These examples were gathered by browsing stackoverflow to see if any of the solutions work, yet to no avail. I can also post the Helper Classes used (such as HttpActionResultExtensions.cs which adds the "AddHeader" method to the result).

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    private UserService _userService = new UserService();

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]LoginRequest loginData)
    {
        IHttpActionResult response;
        LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse { };


        if (loginData == null)
        {
            loginResponse.responseMsg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            response = ResponseMessage(loginResponse.responseMsg);
            return response;
        }

        User user = _userService.Authenticate(loginData.Username, loginData.Password);

        if (user.Token == null)
        {
            loginResponse.responseMsg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            response = ResponseMessage(loginResponse.responseMsg);
            return response;
        }

        /*Request.Content.Headers.Add("Authorisation", user.Token);
        Request.Headers.Add("Authorisation", user.Token);
        return Ok(loginResponse);*/

        /*HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        responseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Authorisation", user.Token);
        //response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Filename");
        responseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorisation");
        ResponseMessageResult responsez = new ResponseMessageResult(responseMessage);
        return responsez;*/

        //return Ok(user).AddHeader("Authorisation", user.Token);
        //return new HeaderActionResult(Tuple.Create("Authorization", user.Token));

        var Result = new { Status = "Ok", Message = user };

        var Response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Result);
        Response.Headers.Add("Authorisation", user.Token);

        return ResponseMessage(Response);
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe what you want to do is not simply return response but do `return new ContextResult { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK, Content = response}` I believe this should solve your issue.

Comment: @jack not sure if you understood the question, yet your answer does not resolve anything. Content in ContextResult has to be String, my result is an Object

Comment: Sorry for that. I think you can create a JObject and send that JObject in the response. You can find JObject as part of JSON.NET nuget package.